# How to get an instance of scala.Unit in Java code

Tags: scala-java-interop

I'm trying to implement `(A, B) => Unit` from Java code. How do I return a value for Unit?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Unit is the scala equivalent of void in Java, so there's no need to return anything.

Comment: I don't think you've answered the question. If a Scala API accepts a function of (A, B) => Unit, the type of that function will be Function2<A, B, Unit>, which means you need to provide an implementation of apply which is of type Unit apply(A a, B b). Scala knows that Unit is void, but Java doesn't, the Java compiler will force you to return something, so the question is, what do you return? I think the answer is null.